# SigMa micro touchpad returning LEFT_META+S for three finger tap

Tags: linux, touchpad, input-device

I have a tablet/convertible with a keyboard integrating a touchpad. The way the latter works is peculiar and does not nicely accomodate for linux usage.
Specifically, even if everything seems OK at first sight, after some usage you'll notice that the three finger tap rather than returning a *mouse* event, returns a *keyboard* event that is the pressure of the left window key together with the letter "S".

Does anybody know if it is possible to remap this key sequence into a middle button *mouse* event?